# Lookup values based on corresponding date between two-column range in Python

Tags: python, sql, date

Sorry before that I am trying to read the postgresql script and import to SQL server database but I keep getting below error
TypeError: read_sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'con'

If there is any wrong with my script below, appreciate if anyone can help or advise me further on this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko3bj.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) I've also removed the conflicting RDBMS tags; if your question is about a particular one then [edit] your question to tag the *actual* (R)DMBS you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

You can subset your df2 with the columns of interest.

```
df2_subset = df2[['U_ORS_ID', 'EffDt_Function']]
```

Then you make a merge with:

```
df1= pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2_subset, left_on='operator_admin', right_on='U_ORS_ID', how='left')
```